# grid-area css rule not working on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Trying to figure out why it's saying "**unknown property**" for a `grid-area` rule I am setting. Trying to set it to `sidebar`, I get "**unknown property**" in chrome dev tools.

[image]

Any work-arounds for chrome? This works fine in Firefox.

Comment: I'm gonna answer you by a question the other way a round, what makes you think you can use sidebar as a property of `grid-area`?

Comment: @user10089632 you can use custom indents in `grid-area`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area

Comment: Oops, I forget about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the error above, my guess is that you forgot a dot before `sidebar` if `sidebar` is a class or a `#` if it is an Id

Here's the code, replace just your own values
within `grid-template-areas` you know that every apparition of an element fills a rectangle you can play with it, the only rule that the whole layout of an element would be a rectangle too, you can not make like an "L" shape

I trust that you know how use distribution of space especially with `fr`s to change the portion that your sidebar will take.

```css
    .sidebar{
     grid-area:sidebar;
      background:aqua;

    }
    .grid_container{
     display:grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr;
     grid-template-areas:
     "sidebar ."
     "sidebar .";
      background:pink;
      height:300px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="grid_container">
      <div class="sidebar">side bar here</div>
      other content here
    </div>
```

Comment: This is working for both Chrome and Firefox, it would be easier to guess the error if it the code was a text rather than screen shot

Comment: That would be true if I didn't mention it working properly in firefox :). The screenshot is showing `.sid(newline)ebar`, the class is `.sidebar` just one word. I think it's just dev tools putting it to a new line. You are right though, that would have been avoided if I provided the css as well. I will try your answer out (compare what you have to me) if you're saying it works in chrome, perhaps I do have a mistake somewhere. Thanks for the help

Comment: **update, I will have to check on my work computer what version of chrome it's running, but it seems to work on my PC at home chrome.

Comment: Wow, somehow was on version 55, updating now to see if it's not supported on 55. After updating to 63.xx it works fine.